# how to store an xml tag as an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, xml-parsing

in my app i am parsing an xml file. In the xml file i am having 50 tags of the same name `question` , now i want to store all the tag named as question as an array....

Among those tags saved i want only one question tag to be placed in a text view....

how to perform this....pls help me.....

Comment: Is the question how to parse xml?

Comment: no... i want store the parsed tag in an array....

Comment: For example if you use SAX you can add object string with question to array every time you read one (in class extended from DefaultHandler). Than you write accessor for that array.

Comment: i am using SAX parser, can you give me an example so that i will be able to understand.....

Comment: I have put it in new answer. It more than comment length constraint.
It is custom handler class. I code you will use smth like

SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();

XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

CustomHandler myExampleHandler = new CustomHandler();

xr.setContentHandler(myExampleHandler);

xr.parse(new InputSource(byteStream));

ArrayList<String> array = myExampleHandler.getResult();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class CustomHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    private ArrayList<String> questionList;
    private boolean questionBuffering;
    private StringBuilder sb;



    @Override
    public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
    questionList = new ArrayList<String>();
    } 

    @Override
    public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
    } 

    @Override
    public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
        if (localName.equals("question")) {
            questionBuffering = true;
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
        if(questionBuffering) {
            sb.append(ch, start, length);
        }

    } 

    @Override
    public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
        if (localName.equals("question")) {
            questionBuffering = false;
        questionList.add(sb.toString());
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getResult() {
        return questionList;
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DOM parser, here is a [link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html) to the DocumentBuilder class.

Once you use the `parse` method out of `DocumentBuilder` and get your `Document` you can use a function like this to get the items as a `NodeList`:

```
    public static NodeList getNodesByName(Document doc, String nodeName)
    {
            Element docEle = doc.getDocumentElement();
            NodeList list = docEle.getElementsByTagName(nodeName);
            return list;
    }
```

In your case you would pass in the Document object you created by parsing the XML and then `question` as your `nodeName`.

Once you have your NodeList, you can iterate through it using a for loop and the `.item()` method.

```
            if(list != null && list.getLength() > 0) {
                for(int i = 0 ; i < list.getLength();i++) {
                    Element element = (Element)list.item(i);
                    String textVal = element.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                    //Once you get the value you can put it into your
                    //array or just use it here.
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483869/how-to-parse-an-xml-file-in-an-android-app/5483938#5483938) seems easily adaptable to your needs. In the example the questions are stored in a map, but it is easy to change this to an `ArrayList` or an array.