# how to print the content in an XML file in android

Tags: android, textview, xml-parsing

hi i am trying to parse an xml file using SAXparser. I followed the example given in the following link,

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488185/how-to-store-an-xml-tag-as-an-array-in-java`

now i want to know how to print the output in my device. i want the output to be printed in a text view.

Comment: you are getting data in the ArrayList ?? arent you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using TextView in your application.Check out the basic tutorial to use TextView in android.Visit this [link](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html#create).

Also see this link to see attributes of XML for TextView & methods used to handle it programmatically.Visit this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html).To set the value of TextView use [setText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.widget.TextView.BufferType%29) method.